# recycle view not showing

Tags: android, firebase

I'm not able to see the recycle view, not sure where It has gone wrong. It would be great if you can help me.

### Fragment

```
public class CallDurationFragment extends Fragment {

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ArrayList<CallHistroy> callList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CallHistroy> callListTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CallHistroy> callObject = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<CallHistroy> callListText = new ArrayList<>();
    private CallDurationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private RecyclerView rvCall;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter callAdaptor;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager;
    private EditText phoneNumber;
    private static final int        DIALOG_DATE_PICKER  = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_callduration_list, container, false);

        phoneNumber = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(editTextSearchKeyPhoneNo);


        Context context = getActivity();
        rvCall = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvCallDuration);
        rvCall.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvCall.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
        eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                callListTemp =  getAllCallRecords();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < callListTemp.size() ; i++)
                    if(callListTemp.get(i).getPhoneNumber().contains(s.toString()) )
                        callListText.add(callListTemp.get(i));
                callList = calculateIncomingOutgoing();
                callAdaptor = new CallDurationAdapter(getActivity(), callList);
                rvCall.setAdapter(callAdaptor);
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
            }
        });
        callList = calculateIncomingOutgoing();
        callAdaptor = new CallDurationAdapter(getActivity(), callList);
        rvCall.setAdapter(callAdaptor);
        return rootView;
    }
    public ArrayList<CallHistroy> getAllCallRecords(){
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
        ref.child("Call").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                callObject.clear();
                HashMap<String,Object> call = null;
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while(items.hasNext()){
                    DataSnapshot item = items.next();
                    Log.e("Listener",item.toString() );
                    call =(HashMap<String, Object>) item.getValue();
                    callObject.add(new CallHistroy(call.get("phoneNumber").toString(),call.get("mode").toString(),call.get("duration").toString(), call.get("date").toString(),item.getKey()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return callObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<CallHistroy> calculateIncomingOutgoing(){
        if(callListText.size() > 0){
            callList = callListText;
        }else {
            callList = getAllCallRecords();
        }
        ArrayList<CallHistroy> callHistroyIncomingOutgoing = new ArrayList<>();
        if(callList.size() > 0){
            if(callList.get(0).getMode().equals("Outgoing")) {
                callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.add(new CallHistroy(callList.get(0).getPhoneNumber(), "0", callList.get(0).getDuration()));
            }else{
                callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.add(new CallHistroy(callList.get(0).getPhoneNumber(), callList.get(0).getDuration(), "0"));
            }
        }
        for( int i = 1  ; i < callList.size() ; i++){
            boolean setValue = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.size() ;j++){
                if( callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.get(j).getPhoneNumber().equals(callList.get(i).getPhoneNumber())){
                    setValue = true;

                     int incoming = Integer.parseInt(callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.get(j).getIncomingDuration());
                    int outgoing =  Integer.parseInt( callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.get(j).getOutgoingDuration());
                    int duration = Integer.parseInt( callList.get(i).getDuration());
                    if(callList.get(i).getMode().equals("Outgoing")) {
                        callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.get(j).updateDuration(String.valueOf(incoming), String.valueOf(outgoing + duration));
                    }else{
                        callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.get(j).updateDuration(String.valueOf(incoming + duration), String.valueOf(outgoing));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!setValue) {
                if(callList.get(i).getMode() == "Outgoing") {
                    callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.add(new CallHistroy(callList.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), "0", callList.get(i).getDuration()));
                }else{
                    callHistroyIncomingOutgoing.add(new CallHistroy(callList.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), callList.get(i).getDuration(), "0"));
                }
            }
        }
        return  callHistroyIncomingOutgoing;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof CallListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (CallDurationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

### Adaptor

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<CallDurationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CallHistroy> mCalls;
    private Context mContext;

    public CallDurationAdapter(Context context, List<CallHistroy> calls) {
        mCalls = calls;
        mContext = context;
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public CallDurationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View callDurationView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_call_duration_details, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(callDurationView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CallDurationAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        final CallHistroy ch = mCalls.get(position);

        // Set item views based on your views and data model
            viewHolder._phoneNoTextView.setText(ch.getPhoneNumber());
            viewHolder._incomingTextView.setText(ch.getIncomingDuration());
            viewHolder._outgoingTextView.setText(ch.getOutgoingDuration());
            final String key = ch.getKey();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCalls.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView _phoneNoTextView;
        public TextView _incomingTextView;
        public TextView _outgoingTextView;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            _phoneNoTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_duration_phone_no);
            _incomingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_duration_outing_total_call);
            _outgoingTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvs_duration_incoming_total_call);

        }
    }
}
```

### Activity

```
public class CallDurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_duration);
        CallDurationFragment newFragment = new CallDurationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.recordFragmentContainer, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void refreshCallDuration(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallDurationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onBackCallDuration(View v) {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

### Object

```
public class CallHistroy implements Comparable<CallHistroy> {

    String phoneNumber;
    String mode;
    String duration;
    String date;
    String key;
    String incomingDuration;
    String outgoingDuration;
    int totalIncoming;
    int totalOutgoing;

    public CallHistroy(String _phontNumber, String _incomingDuration, String _outgoingDuration ){
        setPhoneNumber( _phontNumber );
        setIncomingDuration( _incomingDuration );
        setOutgoingDuration( _outgoingDuration );
    }

    public CallHistroy(String _date, int _totalIncoming, int _totalOutgoing ){
        setDate(_date);
        setTotalIncoming( _totalIncoming );
        setTotalOutgoing( _totalOutgoing );
    }

    public void updateCall(int _totalIncoming, int _totalOutgoing){
        setTotalIncoming( _totalIncoming );
        setTotalOutgoing( _totalOutgoing );
    }

    public void updateDuration(String _incomingDuration, String _outgoingDuration){
        setOutgoingDuration( _incomingDuration );
        setIncomingDuration( _outgoingDuration );
    }

    public CallHistroy(String _phoneNumber, String _mode, String _duration, String _date ){
        setPhoneNumber( _phoneNumber );
        setDuration( _duration );
        setDate( _date );
        setMode( _mode );
    }

    public CallHistroy(String _phoneNumber, String _mode, String _duration, String _date, String _key ){
        setPhoneNumber( _phoneNumber );
        setDuration( _duration );
        setDate( _date );
        setMode( _mode );
        setKey( _key );
    }

    public String getIncomingDuration() {
        return incomingDuration;
    }

    public String getOutgoingDuration() {
        return outgoingDuration;
    }

    public int getTotalIncoming() {
        return totalIncoming;
    }

    public int getTotalOutgoing() {
        return totalOutgoing;
    }

    public void setIncomingDuration(String incomingDuration) {
        this.incomingDuration = incomingDuration;
    }

    public void setOutgoingDuration(String outgoingDuration) {
        this.outgoingDuration = outgoingDuration;
    }

    public void setTotalIncoming(int totalIncoming) {
        this.totalIncoming = totalIncoming;
    }

    public void setTotalOutgoing(int totalOutgoing) {
        this.totalOutgoing = totalOutgoing;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull CallHistroy callHistroyObject) {

        String[] part = callHistroyObject.date.split("/");
        String[] part1 = date.split("/");
        int date = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
        String _year = part[2];
        int year = Integer.parseInt(_year.substring(0,4));

        int date1 = Integer.parseInt(part1[0]);
        int month1 = Integer.parseInt(part1[1]);
        String _year1 = part1[2];
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(_year1.substring(0,4));
        if(year > year1)
            return  -1;
        else if(month > month1)
            return  -1;
        else if(date >date1)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your layout manager before it's created

```
rvCall.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

should be

```
eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
rvCall.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
```

Comment: That was so obvious, start from here first, an if it continues, we need to dig deeper, you can not set the layout manager before you create an instance of it. It is the other way around as @samuel-eminet said above.